# How do I change the value of the last index in an array?

Tags: assembly, tasm

I have declared an array of 8 elements each of size two bytes.

`ar dw 8 dup(6)`

How can I change the value of the last index of this array(ar)?

Comment: Do you know how to write to memory? Do you know the address of the last item? Can you put those two together?

Comment: not really, we just started so im familiar with the methods..

Comment: Try `mov word [ar+2*7], 7`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a template of a TASM program for you:

```
.MODEL small
.486
.STACK 1000h

.DATA
    ar      DW 8 DUP (6)
    decstr  DB 8 ('$')

.CODE
main PROC
    mov ax, @DATA                       ; Initialize DS - Don't forget it!
    mov ds, ax

; You might count the array from 1 to 8, but the computer counts from 0 to 7.
; So, decrement the wished index by 1: (LENGTH arr - 1)
; Since a WORD consumes 2 bytes, the index has to be multiplied by this size,
; so that the computer can point into the array at the right address.
; The size of a WORD (2 bytes) can be determined by the directive TYPE
LASTINDEX =  (LENGTH ar - 1) * TYPE ar

    mov [ar + LASTINDEX],  7

; Print the decimal numbers of the array to the console
    lea si, [ar]                        ; SI gets the address of ar
    mov cx, 8                           ; Counter - do the loop eight times
    L1:
    mov ax, [si]                        ; AX gets the value of the element
    lea di, [decstr]                    ; DI gets the address of decstr
    call ax2dec
    mov WORD PTR [di], '$ '             ; Insert a space into the string
    mov ah, 09h                         ; DOS function: print string
    lea dx, [decstr]                    ; DX gets the address of decstr
    int 21h                             ; Call DOS
    add si, 2                           ; Set the pointer to the next element
    loop L1                             ; Do it CX times

    mov ax, 4C00h                       ; DOS function:Exit with Code 0
    int 21h                             ; Call DOS
main ENDP

ax2dec PROC STDCALL USES ax bx cx dx es ; Args: AX - number; DI - pointer to string
    push ds                             ; Initialize ES for STOSB
    pop es
    mov bx, 10                          ; Base 10 -> divisor
    xor cx, cx                          ; CX=0 (number of digits)

  Loop_1:
    xor dx, dx                          ; Clear DX for division
    div bx                              ; AX = DX:AX / BX   Remainder DX
    push dx                             ; Push remainder for LIFO in Loop_2
    inc cx                              ; inc cl = 2 bytes, inc cx = 1 byte
    test ax, ax                         ; AX = 0?
    jnz Loop_1                          ; No: once more

  Loop_2:
    pop ax                              ; Get back pushed digits
    or al, 00110000b                    ; Conversion to ASCII
    stosb                               ; Store only AL to [ES:DI] (DI is a pointer to a string)
    loop Loop_2                         ; Until there are no digits left
    mov byte ptr es:[di], '$'           ; Termination character for 'int 21h fn 09h'
    ret
ax2dec ENDP                             ; Ret: DI - pointer to terminating '$'

END main                                ; Directive to stop the compiler.
```

If the examples of your teacher differ, then ask them why! TASM is ancient, but its teachers are even more ancient ;-)

Comment: I just need the commend itself, not the entire template

Comment: @Moshiko: You haven't tried the template, right? If I already do your homework for you, then you can also find what is essential for you.

Answer (score 0):

@fuz's comment was enough to answer your question.

```
mov word [ar+2*7], 7
```

===

The index of your first element is [ar].

Your array has 8 elements each of size two bytes (a word).

So naturally the last index would be [ar+2*(8-1)]. ([ar+16] wouldn't be within the bounds of the array as it would refer to the next two bytes).

===

Just in case if you're thinking why other possibilities are being neglected, here's a short explanation for you.

The instruction `mov` is used to transfer a value between two registers or a register and a memory location. Memory to Memory transfer isn't possible due to it's physical limitations. You can use a temporarily use a register to achieve it though. (3 ins)

Note: Transfer means copy.

Now by default mov transfers a byte to a memory location, if it's a raw value or the it's the higher or lower byte of a register.

To keep things short we can use word to tell the assembler that the given address will receive a 2 byte value, so manage the transfer accordingly.

===

Comment: Hey @Moshiko, which software do you use to write assembly code?

Comment: TASM uses `word ptr`, NASM uses `word`.  Actually, TASM probably works with `mov [ar+2*7], 7` because it magically knows `ar` is a "word" array, and that implies an operand-size.

Comment: `mov mem, imm` is possible; you left that out of your list of what `mov` can do.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV.html

Comment: @PeterCordes Point to be noted.

Comment: mov mem[ory], imm[?] Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Actually I needed some help...A feedback perhaps... What are the things you wish were there in your software which uses TASM/NASM? or if you're using the assembler+linker directly from the console (just like me), what are the things you wish were there? Maybe things that you do but anyways don't pay attention to. or some out of the box feature that exists in some other app altogether, but you wish were there in your software/..., to make your life more easier or productive.. Others can put their opinions if they wish to ()

Comment: I'm using mem as shorthand for memory, yes.  "imm" is an immediate operand, embedded in the machine code.  Opcodes like `C7 /0 iw  MOV r/m16, imm16` in the Intel manual I linked.  (Look up the original PDF for the intro section if you don't know how to read the entries, or see [How to read the Intel Opcode notation](//stackoverflow.com/q/15017659) which extracts that part of the docs.)  I'm talking about an instruction with no register operands like the OP was asking about; `mov [memory], immediate`

Comment: Not sure what you're tying to ask in your last comment.  The obvious missing features in NASM and GAS are a way to use [What methods can be used to efficiently extend instruction length on modern x86?](//stackoverflow.com/q/48046814) to lengthen previous instructions instead of inserting NOPs for align directives.  And also more flexible alignment, like align to 4 bytes past a 64-byte boundary.  Would be handy for microbenchmarking sometimes. Also a better smartalign package that uses long NOPs better for P6 / SnB-family.

Comment: I've never used TASM; DOS is obsolete and uninteresting.